# Gradle Subproject Not Importing Dependencies from Local build.gradle File

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I inherited a JVM* project at work that contains a `settings.gradle` file but no `build.gradle` file and no Gradle Wrapper.

I have created a new Java w/ Spring Boot project from the `start.spring.io` initializer. I installed this new project, `check_forecast` as a subproject of the root project `validation_checks`. This subproject has a `build.gradle` file, but no `settings.gradle` file.
To clarify, the root project, `validation_checks` is the legacy project that was built before my time at the company. When I unzipped the project boilerplate for the new project, `check_forcast` that I created from `start.spring.io`, I placed it in the root directory of the legacy project `validation_checks` and tried to configure `check_forcast` as a subproject of `validation_checks`.

When I try to build the `check_forecast` model using the command `gradle clean build`, I get errors that the subproject doesn't recognize essential dependencies like `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` despite these dependencies being clearly defined in the subproject's `build.gradle` file. Please see my config files below.

* The project contains Java, Kotlin, *and* Groovy code. It's a mess.

- `settings.gradle` file for the root project, `validation_check`:

```
rootProject.name = 'validation_checks'
include 'check_forecast`
```

- `build.gradle` file for the sub project, `check_forecast`:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.company.processes'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Example of the errors I'm getting when I try to build the subproject:

```
> Task :nyiso_subscription_check:compileJava FAILED
C:\Users\onlydean\Workspace\validation_checks\check_forecast\src\main\java\com\company\check_forecast\domain\RefHourMap.java:3: error: package javax.persistence does not exist
import javax.persistence.*;
^
C:\Users\onlydean\Workspace\validation_checks\check_forecast\src\main\java\com\company\check_forecast\domain\RefHourMap.java:164: error: cannot find symbol
    @Embeddable
     ^
  symbol:   class Embeddable
  location: class RefHourMap

. . .
```

I can't figure out why my subproject can't see the dependencies defined in it's own `build.gradle` file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please run gradlew build from root and show the output

Comment: There is no gradle wrapper in the root project. Its an old project.

Comment: You said that you created the root project with start.spring.io... Sorry, it's hard to follow your case. Is it possible to post the whole picture?

Comment: @Alexander.Furer My apologies for the confusion. The Root Project is an old legacy project. The new project I created with start.spring.io I unzipped and placed within the root project's root directory.

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: When I run `gradlew build`:

`gradlew` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.